# How to know when a layout with nested RecyclerView is completely rendered?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-inflate

I want to receive a callback when my layout is completely rendered. My layout contains multiple nested RecyclerViews.

Here is what I tried:

- `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on the fragment view: Returns immediately after the fragment layout is rendered. Does not account for child views.
- [`FirstDrawListener`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/codelab-measure-android-view-performance/blob/main/measure-view-performance-start/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/perfmon/FirstDrawListener.java) logic by firebase performance: Again works only for fragment rendering.

```
     getView().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
          }
        )
```